# Keyframe animation for object-position not working in safari

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, css-animations, keyframe

I have a box and an image inside of the box. I am using CSS3 object-fit property for filling the box with image. And I need a moving animation too. I am using keyframe animation for moving the image.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="item">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
</div>
<br>
<button>
animation
</button>
```

My CSS goes here,

```
    .item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 0px 0;

}

.item.active img {
  -webkit-animation: objectMove 2s;
  animation: objectMove 2s;
  /* object-position: 100px 0; */
}

 @-webkit-keyframes objectMove {
  from {
    object-position: 0 0;

  }

  to {
    object-position: 100px 0;

  }
} 

 @keyframes objectMove {
  from {
    object-position: 0 0;

  }

  to {
    object-position: 100px 0;

  }
}
```

And here is my javascript,

```
$('button').click(function(){ $('.item').addClass('active');

setTimeout(function(){ $('.item').removeClass('active'); }, 2000); })
```

> It works fine in chrome, mozilla and edge. But not working in safari.

[Here is the jsfiddle of the same.](https://jsfiddle.net/a0m1uvhn/2/)

Can any one please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-css-object-fit-object-position-properties/#browser-support-and-polyfills

`object-position` with `keyframes` is not fully supported on safari browser so instead of `object-position` i have used `transform:translateX;`

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.item').addClass('active');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.item').removeClass('active');
  }, 2000);
})
```

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform:translateX(0);
}

.item.active img {
  -webkit-animation: objectMove 2s;
  animation: objectMove 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes objectMove {
  from {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(100px);
  }
}

@keyframes objectMove {
  from {
    transform:translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform:translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
</div>
<br>
<button>
animation
</button>
```